# Is it possible to create a temporary python file and import the class and attribute of that .py file

Tags: python, django, temporary-files

I have a requirement where, I have a python file on my desktop and want to create a **temporary** replica of it in my application and import its class objects. As the desktop  ".py" file updates regularly.

Thanks in Advance guyz.. Please suggest me on this

Comment: Once you import the file, changes to it won't affect the loaded code unless you `reload()` the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it.

Only you need add the path of the files ".py" to `sys.path` variable, then you can import all modules locate in this path.

For example, suppose you have a couple of files in this path "/home/usuario/Desktop/my_proyect.py":

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/usuario/Desktop/")

import my_proyect
```

I hope help you ;-)

Comment: Thank you carlos.. it was a great help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with `importlib` http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module
Just pass the path to the temporary file to the `import_module` function.
I don't really understand why you need it but it's possible.